# How do I utilize array defined in a separate function?

Tags: c, arrays

The code below returns a list of ID numbers just like it should. The issue is that it will tally  the quiz count correctly, and the number of ID's, I know because I have the `printf` there. But it will not allow me to use the two-dimensional array. The file is being read because the four digit numbers within the file are being printed from within my while loop. But why can't I do the same thing to Scores? Simply print it as an integer value. And moreover, how am I supposed to put this data back into the main function to calculate the scores if it de-allocates the values? I know you can't pass a whole array.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# define student_Max 40
# define quiz_Max 5   

void getData(int ID[], int Scores[][quiz_Max], int* number_of_students);

int main (void)
{   
    int ID[student_Max];
    int Scores[student_Max][quiz_Max];
    int Hi[quiz_Max];
    int Lo[quiz_Max];
    double Avg[quiz_Max];
    int number_of_students;

    getData(ID, Scores, &number_of_students);
    printf("Loop count and number of students as told by data file: ");
    printf("%d\n", number_of_students);
}

void getData(int ID[], int Scores[][quiz_Max], int* number_of_students)
{   
    int student_count;
    int quiz_count;
    FILE* spIn;

    student_count = 0;       
    spIn = fopen("myfile.dat", "r");

    while (fscanf (spIn, "%d", &ID[student_count]) != EOF)
    { 
        for (quiz_count = 0; quiz_count < quiz_Max; quiz_count++)
        {
            fscanf (spIn, "%d", &Scores[student_count][quiz_count]);
        }

        printf("%d\n", ID[student_count]);        
        student_count++;        
    }

    fclose(spIn);    
    printf("Quizzes: %d\n", quiz_count);
    *number_of_students = student_count;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.   In an open forum, it pays to assume that nobody has any context on what your code "should" be doing, or what you mean when you say it "will not allow me to use the two-dimensional array".

Comment: "But why can't I do the same thing to Scores? Simply print it as an integer value." It's in my paragraph. 

I also mention it needs to come back out of the function to be calculated by a second called function in the main function and printed. "how am I supposed to put this data back into the main function to calculate the scores if it de-allocates the values?"

Comment: "I know you can't pass a whole array." - That is not correct in two ways: 1) You cannot pass an array **as array** 2) You very well can pass a pointer to the first element. Luckily the format parameter is automatically converted to this. And the name of an array is also converted to such a pointer for most usages - including passing as function argument..

Comment: "[Why can't I ] simply print [Scores] as an integer value[?]" -> maybe because it's not an integer value, it's an array of integer values, among other things.

Comment: I'm aware it's an array. This seems to be taking the question out of context. I can print the ID array an integer at a time from within the loop. That's what I'd like to do with Scores.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question. The first part of your question makes no sense, specifically, `it will not allow me to use the two-dimensional array` and `But why can't I do the same thing to Scores? Simply print it as an integer value.` There's no attempt in your code to print Scores. Provide sample input and output.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I figured out how to get the array filled, but once passing it to other functions (not shown in the code here, as I developed it quite a bit more since posting this) I couldn't figure out how to get a calculate function to choose high and low values for each column. I was supposed to be evaluating a list of ids and quizzes using arrays and loops. Our professor hasn't even lectured on two-dimensional arrays yet expects us to use them effectively.